# Logical and Bitwise Operators warning confusion - iOS

Tags: ios, if-statement, operators, bit-manipulation

I have an if else statement and have 2 perfectly proper arguments in there, however the second one if gives me this warning :

> Use of logical '&&' with constant operand

The code used is:

```
else if ( !IS_WIDESCREEN && UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) //No Warning or error
{

}
else if(IS_WIDESCREEN && UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) //Gives me the above warning
{

}
```

NOTE: IS_WIDESCREEN - is defined with the measurements for the iPhone 5 screen.

Any idea why this is??

///Edit:

Added how I defined the iPhone 5

```
#define IS_WIDESCREEN ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )
```

The whole thing is inside this method:

```
-(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfa‌​ceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

Comment: When you say it is defined with the measurements for the iPhone 5 screen do you mean its just hard coded to that size or is it another logical check in its definition?

Comment: Added the code for you, so you can see what I have done

Comment: Is this inside a `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method?

Comment: Yes it is - sorry forgot to mention that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be

```
else if ( !IS_WIDESCREEN && (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)) {  
// ....
} else if(IS_WIDESCREEN && (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)) {  
// ....
}
```

if you're using this inside `shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation` because you're comparing a constant value to `IS_WIDESCREEN`

Comment: Awesome that did the trick!! I'll accept when SO lifts the time limit:-)

Answer (score 1):

If you use a constant in a logical `&&` expression, you get the warning because the constant is irrelevant.  Imagine the constant is non-negative.  The result of `if (x && non-neg-constant)` is identical to `if (x)`.  Likewise, if the constant is zero, `if (x && 0)` will never be true.

Thus, the compiler is warning you, and hinting that maybe you are trying to do a bitwise operation, checking a specific bit to see if it is set.